# Firebase Environmental Config - Added slashes to private_key_id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, continuous-deployment, service-accounts

### Goal

I'm updating the service_account keys and storing them as Firebase Environmental Variables.

### Error

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I see:

```
Silver-Sliver:Issy dchaddportwine$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'development-is'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message.
```

### Issue

Updating with `firebase functions:config:set` introduces extra `\` characters to the string. This is what I see in the terminal after applying `:set` to the `private_key_id`. See the extra backslashes, where `\n` becomes `\\n`?

```
Silver-Sliver:Issy dchaddportwine$ firebase functions:config:set service_account.private_key_id="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE...L5A==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
✔  Functions config updated.

Please deploy your functions for the change to take effect by running firebase deploy --only functions

Silver-Sliver:Issy dchaddportwine$ firebase functions:config:get
{
  "service_account": {
    "private_key_id": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIE...L5A==\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n",
```

### Question

Is this addition of slashes a bug, or it is user error on my part. Should I be updating the private_key_id differently? How do I solve this?

Comment: I also tried this: `Silver-Sliver:Issy dchaddportwine$ firebase functions:config:set test.testy="---stuff---\nxyz123\n123xyz\n---end stuff--"` BUT, it returns this: `"test": {"testy": "---stuff---\\nxyz123\\n123xyz\\n---end stuff--"},`

Comment: This might be a better way to change the config: `firebase functions:config:set service_account="$(cat service-account.json)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TLDR*: Wrap value of key in single quotes and prefix with `$` for special treatment.

**Hypothesis 1**

The escaping of the new lines is done by the shell program.

**Test 1**

Create a script that logs the arguments parsed in the shell.

```
> echo "console.log(process.argv)" > shell-args.js
```

Run

```
> node shell-args.js x="Always\nEscape"

[ '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.1/bin/node',
  '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/Tests/shell-args.js',
  'x=Always\\nEscape' ]
```

**Hypothesis 2**

Concatenating and printing a file as input leaves the shell argument as-is.

```
echo "Always\nEscape" > always_escape
```

**Test 2**

Run

```
> node shell-args.js x="$(< always_escape)"
```

or

```
> node shell-args.js x="`< always_escape`"

[ '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.1/bin/node',
  '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/Tests/shell-args.js',
  'x=Always\nEscape' ]
```

**Hypothesis 3**

Newlines are given special treatment when ANSI C expansion is used.

From the `man bash`

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word  expands  to
>      string,  with  backslash-escaped  characters replaced as specified by the
>       ANSI C standard...**The  expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.**

**Test 3**

Run

```
> node shell-args.js x=$'Always\nEscape'

[ '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.1/bin/node',
  '/Users/alẹ́tilẹ́/Tests/shell-args.js',
  'x=Always\nEscape' ]
```

**Conclusion**

Wrap value of key in single quotes and prefix with `$` for special treatment.

Comment: Here is another way to update the firebase environmental configuration from the downloaded .json file: `firebase functions:config:set service_account="$(cat service-account.json)"`

Comment: Yeah, that works too. The "$(< service-account.json)" is a shortform syntax as is using `cat`

Answer (score 2):

There's a [bug in the Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/371) (open since 2017) which causes it to double-escape newline characters in function config variables.

The easiest workaround is to simply replace them when you access the config variable:

```js
const doubleEscapedValue = functions.config().service_account.private_key_id;
const correctResult = value.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```